# How to keep updating numbers if sum of their mod is > 10 in Swift

Tags: swift

How can get A and B so the sum of their mods would be less then 10? I tried the code below and if number like 15 and 12, its all set. But if numbers like 15 and 17 it keeps running forever. 
Here's the code I tried

```
    a = Int.random(in: 10...100)
    b = Int.random(in: 10...100)
    c = a % 10
    d = b % 10

    while c + d > 10 {
        a = Int.random(in: 10...100)
        b = Int.random(in: 10...100)
    }


    print(a)
    print(b)
```

Comment: Add `print(c)` and `print(d)` to the bottom of the loop and look at the results.

Comment: *Debugging* seems to be a dying art ...

Comment: Hint: Does `c` and `d` ever change in the loop?

Comment: No results. Doesn't print anything. Keeps running.
No, c and d don't change. But how do I change them properly?

Comment: Where are you running this? I see output if I add those statements.

Comment: Both in Xcode and Playground. I see output as well but only if c + d < 10. If c + d > 10 in  Playground it shows that run 30 000 times and more until I stop playground

Comment: Why would the loop get called so many times? What makes the loop exit? Why is that condition not met? @vadian 's hint should have been enough.

Comment: Because I need the sum of the mods to be less then 10. I thought while loop is a great idea.

Comment: try putting `c = a % 10` and `d = b % 10` inside the loop

Comment: Oh, no, Quinn, that doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

`c` and `d` are never updated in your code. So if at the first shot you don't get `a` and `b` right, you're in for an endless loop. You could fix that by updating them inside the while loop. Or maybe, you're thinking of `c` and `d` as functions that get calculated whenever `a` and be `b` change :

```
var a = Int.random(in: 10...100)
var b = Int.random(in: 10...100)

var c: () -> Int = { a % 10 }
var d: () -> Int = { b % 10 }

while c() + d() > 10 {
    a = Int.random(in: 10...100)
    b = Int.random(in: 10...100)
}
```

---

You could also generate `b` in such a way that you'll always be sure that the sum of the mods is less or equal to 10 :

```
var a = Int.random(in: 10 ... 100)
var b = Int.random(in: 1 ... 9) * 10 + Int.random(in: 0 ... 10 - a % 10)
```

With this expression, `b` will take values between 10 and 99, not 100. To adjust the upper bound, you could define `b` as follows :

```
var b = Int.random(in: 1 ... 10) * 10
b += b == 100 ? 0 : Int.random(in: 0 ... 10 - a % 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, man! The functions way works awesomely! Thanks a lot for that expended answer and your time! <3